# How to get image dimensions when loaded with ByteArray?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Using AS3 and AIR I'd like to get image dimensions after loading them in with ByteArray. Using the code below I can manage to load the images ok and even apply scaleX/scaleY successfully but get zero as height/width from the loader size.

```
        private function listFiles():void{
        imagesPath=layout.pathFld.text;
        fileList=new Array;
        var desktop:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath(imagesPath);
        var files:Array = desktop.getDirectoryListing();
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            fileList.push(files[i].nativePath);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
        {
            layout.txtFld.appendText(fileList[i]+"\n");
        }
        loadOneImage();
    }

    private function loadOneImage():void
    {
        var f:String=fileList[counter];
        bytes = new ByteArray();
         myFileStream = new FileStream();
        var myFile:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath(f);

        myFileStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
        myFileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadImage);       
        myFileStream.openAsync(myFile, FileMode.READ);
    }

    private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void 
    {
        if (myFileStream.bytesAvailable)
        {
            myFileStream.readBytes(bytes, myFileStream.position, myFileStream.bytesAvailable);
        }
    }

    private function loadImage(e:Event):void
    {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.loadBytes(bytes);    
        loader.scaleX=.05;
        loader.scaleY=.05;
        var ph:Number=loader.height;
        var pw:Number=loader.width;
        trace("ph/pw="+ph+"/"+pw);
       // I GET ZEROS HERE
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your image dimensions, you can use `Loader.contentLoaderInfo`, but as @Vesper said, you have to wait that its `Event.COMPLETE` event is fired otherwise compiler will fire an error, so you can do like this :

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.loadBytes(bytes);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onContentLoad);
    function onContentLoad(e:Event):void{
        trace('image width : ' + e.target.width);
        trace('image height : ' + e.target.height);         
    }
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly get size of a constructed `DisplayObject`, add it to stage first. If you don't need to keep it on stage, you add, get size, remove, all in a space of four lines of code. Also, even if you do `loadBytes()`, the loader performs loading asynchronously, so you still have to listen for `Event.COMPLETE` prior to trying to get size.